Azure DevOps Pipeline Error: No Agent Found with Version Greater Than 2.220.0
I recently started encountering an error in my Azure DevOps pipeline that previously built without any issues. The error message is as follows:
No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the following demand: Agent.Version. All demands: Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.220.0
Our build agent version is currently 2.170.1.
I am certain that no changes have been made to the pipeline configuration or the project that would cause this issue. Could this be due to a recent software update on the build server or any changes from Azure DevOps itself?
Here are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot the issue:
Verified the agent version in the Default pool, which is 2.170.1.
Checked for recent updates or changes in the project and pipeline configuration.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue. Is there a way to force the pipeline to use the existing agent version, or should I update the agent to a newer version? If updating the agent is the recommended approach, what are the steps to do so?

Did you also check the pool in the YAML file itself?

Can you provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline that contains all the tasks and task versions set in the pipeline? In Azure Pipelines, many tasks has its required demands. Different tasks or task versions might have different demands. When you add these tasks into the pipelines jobs, it will automatically set the required demands to the jobs-level. When you remove the tasks, the demands also get removed automatically.

For Azure Pipelines built-in tasks, you can view them in the docs "Azure Pipelines task reference". You can open the docs of any built-in task from this page to view the Demands from the Requirements of each task.

For your issue, I recommend you try to upgrade all the agents to new version in the pool.

some task require agent version great then 2.xxx, you may upgrade you agent to v3

@BrightRan-MSFT
YAML file contains more than 2374 characters.

@MaxCHien is there any way I can identify the tasks that are required a version greater than 2.170.x ?

@Dinesh, As mentioned above, for Azure Pipelines built-in tasks, you can open the docs of each task to check the required Demands from the Requirements section. Fore the tasks provided by extensions, check the README of the extensions to see if there is any statement for the Demands of the tasks. The recommended way to avoid the issue is to keep the agents are up-to-date.

@Dinesh, You can provide the YAML of the job that reports the error.

@BrightRan-MSFT
steps:
............

task: gitversion/execute@0
name: Execute
inputs:
useConfigFile: $(DetectGitVersionConfig.GitVersionConfigExists)
configFilePath: ${{ parameters.configFilePath }}
displayName: Execute GitVersion

mean time I will check the Requirements section. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.

@Dinesh, Please post formatted YAML content in your question so that it can be well readable. And does the job only contain the gitversion/execute@0 task?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@BrightRan-MSFT This is the(gitversion/execute@0) only task defined in gitversion.yml and there are some PowerShell scripts. I went through the document you mentioned earlier but I could not find a task related to gitversion/execute@0

As we has discussed in above comments, it is recommended to update the agents in your pool to be the latest version.

You can open the agent pool and then click "Update all agents" button to upgrade all the agents in the pool.


You can enable the option "Allow agents in this pool to automatically update" in the pool. When a new agent version is available, it will automatically upgrade the agent before starting to run the pipeline jobs.




In addition, as @Max CHien mentioned, Azure DevOps has released Agent version 3.x. We recommend you consider to upgrade your self-hosted agents to version 3.x. You need to download the installation package of Agent version 3.x and install it on yourself machines. If you no longer need the version 2.x agents, you can uninstall them.


EDIT:
If you are using Azure DevOps Server/TFS (on-premises), the the Agent version 3.x is available starting in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1. The lower versions are not available. See "Agent version 3.x"

Since you are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 with a quite old Update/Patch version (Version Dev18.M170.8), the Agent version 3.x is not available. You can consider to download the latest Agent version 2.x from the GitHub repository (v2.220.0).
In addition, according to the statement in "Azure DevOps Server 2020 Release Notes", if you upgrade to latest Update/Patch version (Update 0.2 Patch 6) of Azure DevOps Server 2020, you should be able to use Agent version 3.x.

EDIT_2:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)

Ensure you have correctly set the checkout task and disabled shallow clone on the task.
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0  # Disable shallow clone.


Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'dotnet-gitversion'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable.

Before the Execute GitVersion (gitversion/execute) task, you need to run the Setup GitVersion (gitversion/setup) task, otherwise the Execute step will fail with this error. See "GitVersion Tasks Usage Examples".

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0

- task: gitversion/setup@1
  displayName: 'Install GitVersion'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
    preferLatestVersion: true

- task: gitversion/execute@1
  displayName: 'Generate Version'



Thanks for the detailed explanation. At this point, I do not want to upgrade the existing agent as some other pipelines are configured to use this agent. Is it okay if I install a new agent on the same machine and set the default pool to use the new agent?

@Dinesh, Sure, you can configure multiple agents with different agent versions in the same pool.

Hi Bright Ran-MSFT,
I tried to create a new agent, but the downloaded VSTS agent version is 2.170.1. This is the version of Azure DevOps Server - Version Dev18.M170.8.
Does this server support only version 2.170.1? In that case, can I download the latest VSTS agent from https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases and install it? Will it work?

@Dinesh, For Azure DevOps Server/TFS, the Agent version 3.x is available starting in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1. See EDIT in my answer.

Hi Bright Ran-MSFT, I have installed 2.220.0 and set the new pool. When I run the build I am getting this error.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Command: dotnet-gitversion C:/agent/vsts-agent/_work/1/s /output json /output buildserver /config C:\agent\vsts-agent_work\1\s\GitVersion.yml
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'dotnet-gitversion'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

@Dinesh, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions. See EDIT_2.

Hi Bright Ran-MSFT, thanks for your response. I have a doubt, with our previous successful build, when I checked the GitVersion logs, the command that executed was
Agent: 'Azure Pipelines'
Command: dotnet-gitversion C:/agent/i1/_work/39/s /output json /output buildserver /config C:\agent\i1_work\39\s\GitVersion.yml
But with the failed build after updating the agent. The command is
Agent: 'Azure Pipelines'
Command: git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
Any thoughts on this?

@Dinesh, This might be related to the update on the agent and the GitTool extension itself.

Hi Bright Ran-MSFT, I have updated the gitversion ymal to setup first before execute task and it worked.  Thanks for your help, mush appreciated.

Hi Bright Ran-MSFT, after setting up the agent. I created a commit with +semver: minor. My package version was 2.1.0 and with the commit, I was expecting to increment the version number by 1, which means 2.2.0 instead the package was updated to 2.1.1. Any idea?
